# Can not deploy adapters due to missing files

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-studio

I am trying to deploy worklight adapters in a MobileFirst 6.3 project and I am getting errors in the console: It is throwing

> Adapter deployment failed: HTTP 500 - Internal Server Error

When I try to build the project it is building and the server is starting. But when I try to deploy the adapter it is throwing an Error with the following stacktrace:

```
[ERROR   ] /Users/915655/Documents/Projects/R2O/New%20Workspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/workarea/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/73/data/cache/com.ibm.ws.app.manager_93/.cache/WEB-INF/lib/ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (No such file or directory)
/Users/915655/Documents/Projects/R2O/New%20Workspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/workarea/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/73/data/cache/com.ibm.ws.app.manager_93/.cache/WEB-INF/lib/ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (No such file or directory)
[ERROR   ] /Users/915655/Documents/Projects/R2O/New%20Workspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/workarea/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/73/data/cache/com.ibm.ws.app.manager_93/.cache/WEB-INF/lib/ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (No such file or directory)
/Users/915655/Documents/Projects/R2O/New%20Workspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/workarea/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/73/data/cache/com.ibm.ws.app.manager_93/.cache/WEB-INF/lib/ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (No such file or directory)
[ERROR   ] Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet 
                                                                                                               ManagementServlet
                                                                                                               WorklightServices
                                                                                                               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.wink.common.internal.i18n.Messages
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.DeploymentConfiguration.initAlternateShortcutMap(DeploymentConfiguration.java:386)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.DeploymentConfiguration.init(DeploymentConfiguration.java:167)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.getDeploymentConfiguration(RestServlet.java:202)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.createRequestProcessor(RestServlet.java:138)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.init(RestServlet.java:103)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:325)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.filter.HSTSFilter.doFilter(HSTSFilter.java:110)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
    at [internal classes]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it cannot find a file:

> ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (No such file
>   or directory)

- Make sure you're using a Supported version of Eclipse, which must be Eclipse Java EE Kepler or Luna.
- Verify that the problem is not the spaces that you have in the workspace name ("new workspace").
- Try with a new Eclipse installation

Comment: I tried with a workspace with no spaces. And i am just using the same eclipse environment which my friend is using but its working for him and its not working for me

Comment: Try either a fresh installation, or copy and use his installation. What is the difference between your workstation and his? Windows? Mac? Linux?

Comment: Yeah tried those options and only difference that i could find between my machine and his is the java version I'm having java 1.7.67 and he is having java 1.7.75

Comment: Yeah and I even tried changing my jdk to his version even then no use